# Select multiple list items using angularjs

Tags: list, angularjs

I'm trying to select a particular list item from elements in an unordered list. It should appear as selected, which I need to show by changing some background.

I was trying to use `$index` which comes as undefined as I was trying to use it within the `<li>` element.

Can I achieve this from within `angularjs`, without using a checkbox or jQuery?

Comment: You're going to need to share your code if you want people to be able to advise you on your use case....

Comment: You mean something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/kuC3PK?p=preview

Comment: ^ That is a great plunker to get you going. I would personally use a directive in my <li> elements, and bind them to a click. That way you have more functionality available to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on your particular need but maybe you can write the result of the selection directly in the item like so

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'selected':item.selected}">
        <a href="" ng-click="toggle(item)">{{item.text}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

where

```
$scope.toggle = function (item) {
    item.selected = !item.selected;
};
```

See a minimalist demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/9qLm4/1/

Or you could use `$index` to store your selection into a different `array` like so

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'selected':selection.indexOf($index)!=-1}">
        <a href="" ng-click="toggle($index)">{{item}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

where

```
$scope.selection = [];

$scope.toggle = function (idx) {
    var pos = $scope.selection.indexOf(idx);
    if (pos == -1) {
        $scope.selection.push(idx);
    } else {
        $scope.selection.splice(pos, 1);
    }
};
```

See a minimalist demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/j5T2y/2/

I have a preference for the former, which is more consistent.

Comment: Really appreciate your approach. But what if I want to add a click event on <li> element and not have a hyperlink. In that case you would not be able to have the value of index.

Comment: Should work with only a <li>. Modified example here : http://jsfiddle.net/djXVt/1/

Comment: Thanks @ovmjm your answers helped me for my requirement