# How to do multiple selection on list item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

[Can I make multiple selection on the given image?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jop1.png)

I have tried  but I want tick mark on the multiple selection using Ionic.
I am using Ionic framework, Please provide me with the solution in Ionic.

`<ion-radio ng-model="filter.yellow" ng-repeat="chat in chats">{{chat.name}}</ion-radio>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797364/select-multiple-list-items-using-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ionic projects you would instead use the [ion-checkbox](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionCheckbox/) feature. You could then apply css to either make it look more like the ion-radio, switch classes around to make it look exactly like the ion-radio or even make it bespoke to you application.

Comment: Is there any option in ionic, long press select option?

Comment: I don't believe io-checkbox has a long press option, but the docs would be the best place to confirm that. If you're happy with my answer, could you mark it as correct? The click the tick icon? Thank you.